# The powerful connection

Tags: code-golf, grid

## Introduction

There is a plantation defined by one big *square-board* like this one:

[image]

The numbers inside each small square represents its area's value/cash/...

The farmer needs help to find the *N* squares that connected *(it means all N squares should have at least one shared border)* give him the greatest value.

For example:

If `N=1`, then the output must be `140`.

If `N=6`, then..

[image]

..the output must be `315`.

## Challenge

Your program/function must take the the **matrix's values** and the number **N** as input/arguments and must output **the powerful connection**'s value.

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Examples

Input:

```
10 -7 11 7 3 31
33 31 2 5 121 15
22 -8 12 10 -19 43
12 -4 54 77 -7 -21
2 8 6 -70 109 1
140 3 -98 6 13 20
6
```

Output: `315`

---

Input:

```
35 -7
-8 36
2
```

Output: `29`

Comment: Some brute force algorithms for this could be very slow. Are there any restrictions on time for cases like the first test case?

Comment: @steveverrill. For this challenge, no time complexity will count, but if you answer this and prove that your method is efficiently better than brute force I will gladly upvote your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 190 bytes

```js
(m,n)=>m.map((a,r)=>a.map((_,c)=>f(r,c,[0],0)),o=f=(x,y,s,t)=>s[n]?o>t?0:o=t:s.indexOf(w=x+","+y)<0&&m[y]&&(v=m[y][x])<1/0&&f(x+1,y,s=[...s,w],t+=v)+f(x,y+1,s,t)+f(x-1,y,s,t)+f(x,y-1,s,t))|o
```

### Explanation

Takes the matrix as an array of arrays.

Starts from each square then uses a recursive function to test every possible combination. This is a brute-force approach, but it finishes almost instantly for the first test case on my machine.

```js
(m,n)=>
  m.map((a,r)=>                 // for each row
    a.map((_,c)=>               // for each column
      f(r,c,[0],0)              // start checking paths from the coordinate of the square
    ),
    o=                          // o = output number (max total)
    f=(x,y,s,t)=>               // recursive function f, x & y = current square, t = total
                                // s = array of used squares (starts as [0] so length = +1)
      s[n]?                     // if we have used n squares
        o>t?0:o=t               // set o to max of o and t
      :s.indexOf(w=x+","+y)<0&& // if the square has not been used yet
      m[y]&&(v=m[y][x])<1/0&&   // and the square is not out of bounds
                                // ( if value of square is less than Infinity )

        // Check each adjacent square
        f(x+1,y,
          s=[...s,w],           // clone and add this square to s
          t+=v                  // add the value of this square to the total
        )
        +f(x,y+1,s,t)
        +f(x-1,y,s,t)
        +f(x,y-1,s,t)
  )
  |o                            // return output
```

### Test

```js
var solution = (m,n)=>m.map((a,r)=>a.map((_,c)=>f(r,c,[0],0)),o=f=(x,y,s,t)=>s[n]?o>t?0:o=t:s.indexOf(w=x+","+y)<0&&m[y]&&(v=m[y][x])<1/0&&f(x+1,y,s=[...s,w],t+=v)+f(x,y+1,s,t)+f(x-1,y,s,t)+f(x,y-1,s,t))|o
```

```html
<textarea rows="7" cols="40" id="Matrix">10 -7 11 7 3 31
33 31 2 5 121 15
22 -8 12 10 -19 43
12 -4 54 77 -7 -21
2 8 6 -70 109 1
140 3 -98 6 13 20</textarea><br />
N = <input type="number" id="N" value="6" /><br />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(Matrix.value.split('\n').map(x=>x.split(' ').map(z=>+z)),N.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```